# angular NGRX: Not able to select single value in ngrx entity based on id

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I am trying to select an object by Id from the entity state. Below is my reducer.

```
 export interface MessageState extends EntityState<Message> {
  // additional entities state properties
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Message> = createEntityAdapter<Message>({
  selectId: (msg: Message) => msg.messageId,
});

export const initialState: MessageState = adapter.getInitialState({
  // additional entity state properties
  loaded: false,
  loading: false,
});

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: MessageActionsUnion): MessageState {
  switch (action.type) {

    case MessageActionTypes.UPSERT_Message: {
      return { ...state, loading: true, loaded: false };
    }

    case MessageActionTypes.UPSERT_Message_SUCCESS: {
      return adapter.upsertOne(action.payload.Message,
        {
          ...state, loaded: true, loading: false,
        });

    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my index.ts file

```
export interface State extends fromRoot.AppState {
  queueModule: QueueState;
}

export interface QueueState {
  msgHeaders: fromMsgHeaders.MessageHeaderState
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<QueueState> = {
  msgHeaders: fromMsgHeaders.reducer

};

export const getQueueState$ = createFeatureSelector<QueueState>('queueModule');
```

I am trying to form a selector when passed an Id will return the value from the entity.

```
    export const selectMessages = createSelector(
      fromFeatures.getQueueState$,
      (state: fromFeatures.QueueState) => state.msgs
    );

    export const {
      selectAll: selectAllMessages,
      selectEntities: selectMessagesEntities,
      selectIds: selectMessagesIds,
      selectTotal: selectMessagesTotal
    } = adapter.getSelectors(selectMessages);
```

I looked at many resources, but none are clear on how to select an object by passing the id.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can see nothing in here that tries to select any object by passing some Id somewhere... My guess is that you want to get this mysterious message by its id... but I can see no storage for those messages to begin with. It is completely unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ngrx/entity` does provide a getEntityValueById after their release of v6.1.0 ([ngrx entity changelog](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#610-2018-08-01)) where they have introduced `dictionary`.

Thus using this, I was able to pull a single value of an entity by its id in the below way.

```
// in the selector
import { Dictionary} from '@ngrx/entity;

export const getMessageById = () => {
  return createSelector(
    selectMessagesEntities,                
    (entities: Dictionary<Message>, props: { messageId: number }) => {
      return entities[props.messageId];
    },
  );
};


//to call the selector


this.msg$ = this.store.pipe(select(
      fromStore.getMessageById(), { messageId: 10 }
    )).pipe(
      map(
        (message: Message) => {
          return this.msg = message;
        },
      )
    );
```

Also a great reference for this approach has been documented 
[here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8).

Answer (score 1):

`@ngrx/entity` doesn't provide a `getOneById` selector.

In most of the cases, this is something you shouldn't have to do.

That being said there are ways of creating a selector which does exactly this, for more info see (NgRx: Parameterized selectors)[https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8].

For example:

```
export const getCount = createSelector(
  getCounterValue, 
  (counter, props) => counter * props.multiply
);

export const selectCustomer = (id: string) => createSelector(
  selectCustomers,
  customers => customers[id]
);
```

Comment: Why would i not need `getOneById`? Selecting a specific item of a list seems very default to me

Comment: Agree with @Deitsch here. The use case I run into repeatedly is I want to update one or two properties on a single entity in my reducer. I don't see another way to do this besides selecting that one entity by id, updating the required properties then writing it back to the store with upsertOne().